# how can check the username and password in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

in login page in c#,how can I check if the username and password are match with username and password in sqlserver to login the next page??
i don't wanna use store procedure!

Comment: O.o try something plz, and if you get any error you can post here

Comment: Please show your code . where are you stuck  ..?

Comment: Please Check following link. it will help you.  
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408306/Understanding-and-Implementing-ASP-NET-Custom-Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";


    Int32 verify;
    string query1 = "Select count(*) from Login where ID='" + idBox.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordBox.Text + "' ";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    con.Open();
    verify = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();
    if (verify > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("succesful.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("unsuccesful.aspx",true);
    }

}
```

But you need to go for Stored Procedure to avoid [SQL INJECTION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: No, you don't need to use stored procedures. Just use prepared statements instead.